# what do i have to do if break a wallahi

Tags: islamic-basis

when i was 8-10 i used to break wallahis all the time but now I have realized I did a very bad thing, for example I said wallahi ill give u this for example a pokemon card, but I did it multiple times can anyone tell what I can do I regret my wallahis very bady but I'm still 11 and don't know how to repay for them, I cannot fast for 3 months because my parents will not let me and idk how to help like 2k ppl :(

Answer (score 0):

As salam alaykum brother,

Bismillah Arrahman Arraheem

The best thing you can do is go to your local Masjid and ask the Sheikh or Imaam for help. But you've come here, so I'll try answering your question.

First of all, when you break a promise with Allah, the first thing you should do is feed 10 needy/homeless people with what you would normally eat. Considering you can't do that, you would have to fast 3 days. I'm pretty sure you are allowed to defy your parents if it's for Islam and they're holding you back from Islam.Don't worry though.

The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) has stated this, “The pen has been raised for three persons (meaning they are not held accountable for what they do): one who is sleeping until he gets up, a child until he reaches the age of puberty, and an insane person until he becomes sane.” (Ahmad, Abu Dawud, At-Tirmidhi, An-Nasa’i, Ibn Majah, and Al-Hakim)

In Islam, puberty is when you become an adult. For a man, you become an adult when 1 of these 3 conditions is met.

1: You have a wet dream (if you don't know what it is, it's better not to look it up since you're still young)
2: You reach the age of 15.
3: You start getting body hair.

If you want to know whether you're considered a child or not, you can do more research on your own. Don't take another person's word for it unless they provided sources. I haven't, but there are sources out there (hadiths) that approve of this.

And at last, perform At-Tawbah (if you don't know what it is, look it up). Allah (SWT) knows best.

Comment: jazakallhulkhair brother i have a question can i preform ghusl for salat at tawbah?